# preg-replace image width, height and style

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

My image looks like this:

```html
<img alt="" width="146" height="109" src="http://url.to/src.jpg" style="float:left" />
```

but i can't figure out how to bring it with preg_replace or preg_replace_callback to this:

```html
<img alt="" src="http://url.to/src.jpg" style="width:146;height:109;float:left">
```

This works with height and width but I can't get the style-element "float:left" added

```
$html='<img alt="" width="146" height="109" src="http://url.to/src.jpg" style="float:left" />';
$pattern = ('/<img[^>]*width="(\d+)"\s+height="(\d+)">/');
preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches);
$style = "<img style=\"width:".$matches[1]."px; height:".$matches[2]."px;\"";
$html = preg_replace($pattern, $style, $html);
```

result of this will be

```html
<img  alt="" style="width:146;height:109" src="http://url.to/src.jpg" style="float:left">
```

which didn't work because of the double style element

Comment: What have you tried, post the reg ex you've tried here so we can help debug it. Nobody's going to write it for you.

Comment: sorry -added a sample to my startpost

Comment: Do you need to use regular expressions? This would be pretty straightforward with DOM functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regular expression

```
<?php

$html='<img alt="" width="146" height="109" src="http://placehold.it/140x200" style="float:left" />';
$pattern = '/(<img.*)width="(\d+)" height="(\d+)"(.*style=")(.*)" \/(>)/';
$style = '$1$4width:$2px;height:$3px;$5';
$html = preg_replace($pattern, $style, $html);
echo $html; //view source of page to see the code change

?>
```

Note the use of brackets '(' ')' to create groups matched that can be later referenced using $1 $2 etc go to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bS7gX6/1) and try out the regular expression.

Above code will result in following, except the last part, that shouldn't matter but you can modify it further.

```
<img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/140x200" style="width:146;height:109;float:left" />
```

Comment: thanks for your help and the awesome regex101.com-link. this will help me to solve these preg_replaces in the future without any problems.